# Fetching URL and converting to UTF-8 Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I would like to do my first project in python but I have problem with coding. When I fetch data it shows coded letters instead of my native letters, for example '\xc4\x87' instead of 'ć'. The code is below:

```
import urllib.request
import sys

page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://olx.pl/")
test = page.read()

print(test)
print(sys.stdin.encoding)
z = "ł"
print(z)
print(z.encode("utf-8"))
```

I know that code here is poor but I tried many options to change encoding. I wrote z = "ł" to check if it can print any 'special' letter and it shows. I tried to encode it and it works also as it should. Sys.stdin.encoding shows cp852.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you read from a `urlopen()` response is *encoded data*. You'd need to first *decode* that data using the right encoding.

You appear to have downloaded UTF-8 data; you'd have to decode that data first before you had text:

```
test = page.read().decode('utf8')
```

However, it is up to the server to tell you what data was received. Check for a characterset in the headers:

```
encoding = page.info().getparam('charset')
```

This can still be `None`; many data formats include the encoding *as part of the format*. XML for example is UTF-8 by default but the XML declaration at the start can contain information about what codec was used for that document. An XML parser would extract that information to ensure you get properly decoded Unicode text when parsing.

You may not be able to print that data; the 852 codepage can only handle 256 different codepoints, while the Unicode standard is far larger.

Answer (score 0):

The *urlopen* is returning to you a *bytes* object. That means it's a raw, encoded stream of bytes. Python 3 prints that in a *repr* format, which uses escape codes for non-ASCII characters. To get the canonical unicode you would have to decode it. The right way to do that would be to inspect the header and look for the encoding declaration. But for this we can assume UTF-8 and you can simply *decode* it as such, not encode it.

```
import urllib.request
import sys

page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://olx.pl/")
test = page.read()
print(test.decode("utf-8"))  # <- note change
```

Now, Python 3 defaults to UTF-8 source encoding. So you can embed non-ASCII like this if your editor supports unicode and saving as UTF-8.

```
z = "ł"
print(z)
```

Printing it will only work if your terminal supports UTF-8 encoding. On Linux and OSX they do, so this is not a problem there.

Comment: Thank you for you help. It looks so easy and I feel confused. I tried something similliar and it did not work. I am a newbie as I told.

Comment: Unicode is difficult, even in Python3. If you're starting out you can get by with copying bits of code, but when you want to / need to get a serious understanding of what's going on, you should watch Ned Batchelder's "Pragmatic Unicode, or, How do I stop the pain?" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc. It really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The others are correct, but I'd like to offer a simpler solution. Use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/). It's 3rd party, so you'll need to install it via pip:

```
pip install requests
```

But it's a lot simpler to use than the `urllib` libraries. For your particular case, it handles the decoding for you out of the box:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://olx.pl/")
print(r.encoding)
# UTF-8
print(type(r.text))
# <class 'str'>
print(r.text)
# The HTML
```

Breakdown:

- `get` sends an HTTP `GET` request to the server and returns the respose.
- We `print` the encoding `requests` thinks the text is in. It chooses this based on the response header Martijin mentions.
- We show that `r.text` is already a decoded text type (`unicode` in Python 2 and `str` in Python 3)
- Then we actually `print` the response.

Note that we don't *have* to `print` the encoding or type; I've just done so for diagnostic purposes to show what `requests` is doing. `requests` is designed to simplify a lot of other details of working with HTTP requests, and it does a good job of it.